# Image tag cause product thumb look disorder in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have installed one plugin under my woocommerce store in order to show appropriate icon awards for wines. When I add image icon which shows in top left corner of woocommerce thing images, and look website on mobile website the image looks disorder and like its squeezed and stretched. If you take a look at website home page http://letmewine.com/ and product "FRANCIACORTA BRUT “ALMA” BELLAVISTA" from mobile phone you will see what I mean. I tried assigning z-index value position to absolute or relative to that image icon and nothing happend. I could use any suggestion what to do here.

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your image is absolute and have set `width:100%`, `height:100%` which makes is stretched. It's because the images is trying to fill the the entire holder which is actually bigger than image size.

You should change your style.css on line 11739 where is the selector for the image ( `.post_featured img` ) and change so your code will become:

```
.post_featured img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it work, but to certain part. If you check it now. The image seems cut of on half in height. How can I avoid this too?

Comment: Well the problem now is that there was another style for that image that was overwritten by you, when adding `!important` to height attribute.
You should remove the `!important` statement and leave it as it is in my example.